# HTML Post With Format "Blog"

Tags: php, html, forms, format

I am working on a personal website, http://dummycode.com and I am having one issue, or rather a bothering time-consuming scenario. Since I am a new user I cannot seem to post more than two links, rather than posting the full link I posted the path after the website link. Example: http://dummycode.com + `/path/path`

I will start off by trying to explain how this is going to work, I have a project directory, or archive, at `/projects` and I am currently trying to facilitate the process of adding a new project to the archive as I continue to add, modify, and change these different projects and there statuses. If you look at, `/projects/wordcounttool` you can see an example of what I need my project archive or information about the project to look like.

This is currently being done by creating a new directory, adding an index.html and editing the project using a template, `/projects/projecttemplate.html`

What I am currently trying to do is create a PHP/HTML form that I can fill out specific information about the project and it automatically creates a directory under `/projects/projectname` and fills in the form with the information I fill out.

I am wondering how I would go about this process? I know I need to make a form and run a specific PHP script that creates a directory, creates an index.html file in that directory, fills in the specific variables in their corresponding spots and finalize it.

Essentially, my question is how would I go about doing this? What would be some initial steps I need to take in order to get this process started? I am just looking to do some research and since I want to learn and do it myself I am not going to use a CMS just yet. I want to learn more about HTML and PHP and see if I can conquer this since it will be a good experience for a 15 year old developer.

Thanks for all the help I can get,
Henry Harris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up URL rewriting. If you're using **Apache** as your webserver, search for `mod_rewrite`, if **nginx**, it has it's own `rewrite` directives, etc.

With that, you can set it up so that every request that comes in to your website, gets handed a PHP script that you specify and in that script you can decide what you need to output based on what URL was used.

For example (this is for Apache), in the simplest case, you can set it up so that everything that is requested from your server gets passed to the same PHP script (index.php), except if it is an existing file like a CSS file or an image file. This goes into `.htaccess` file in the web root (the main directory where your website files are kept.):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
</IfModule>
```

and in that script you can check the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable that will contain the URL requested, for example, if `http://dummycode.com/blog/post/1/` was requested, it will contain `/blog/post/1/`, and then you can just look at the parts of the URL and decide what to do.

Comment: Thank you, I will see what I can do with that.

Comment: You're welcome. I also added an example of a simple case of URL rewriting for Apache.

Comment: Appreciate it. @pilsetnieks

Comment: This is, of course, off topic but I looked at your website and, if I may suggest, if you're sharing your code with others, GitHub (github.com) might be a good place to put it - it's a thriving community for code sharing, in any language, plus git and source control tools in general are a good skill to add to your resume.

Comment: Thank you, I have heard about GitHub before but have never actually checked it out but, I will definitely have to do so now.

Answer (score 0):

A good choice would be to learn jQuery and AJAX so you can control the look and functionality of the UI just as you want it.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into both of those.